# How can we use Django property decorator in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello I trying to use Django property decorator in Django rest framework here my code

**Model.py**

```
class TempCalculate(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def Price(self):
        self.price = (PriceMaster.objects.get(items = self.items)) * self.quantity
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from base.models import TempCalculate

class TempCalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TempCalculate
        fields = "__all__"
```

**api/view.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def TempItem(request):
    queryset = TempCalculate.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TempCalSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

**I trying to access self.price (which I have make property decorator in models.py) in rest api **

Answer (score 0):

Update your property method in your TempCal model. return self.price from Price property method. Use name of the property method as a serializer Meta fields like this.

```
class TempCalculate(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def Price(self):
        self.price = (PriceMaster.objects.get(items = self.items)) * self.quantity
        return self.price


from rest_framework import serializers
from base.models import TempCalculate

class TempCalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TempCalculate
        fields = ['id', 'item', 'quantity', 'create_at', 'create_by', 'Price']
```

Also this is not a code breaking mistake but function and variable name should be in lowercase as stated in [pep8 naming convension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)